# Is there a way for two SVG <tspan> inside of <text> line up at the left edge without specifying an absolute x for the child?

Tags: svg, text, tspan

The following code will show the "World" as a continuous flow of the `x` position.
We can specify `x="200"` for that second `<tspan>` so that it lines up with the "Hello" at the left edge. But is there a way to do it without needing to specify an absolute `x` of `200`?

It is like if we have a `<div>`, and then we have two `<div>`s inside, the left edge will line up, without needing to specify an absolute `x` for the parent and an absolute `x` for the child:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:lang="en" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 400 200">

  <text x="200" y="30">
    <tspan>Hello</tspan>
    <tspan dy="1.2em">World</tspan>
  </text>

</svg>
```

I thought about using

```
  <style>
    text { position: relative }
    tspan { position: absolute; left: 0 }
  </style>
```

and it doesn't work inside of Chrome.

Comment: so you have to specify the absolute `x` twice?  My goal is have a "container" so that children can line up on left edge no matter what absolute `x` the container has. Shouldn't need to specify absolute `x` multiple times

Comment: use a transform and you can set the tspan x to 0 would that count?

Comment: does it work? if it works it should count

Answer (score 2):

You can use a transform to position the text, then the additional tspan x value is 0.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:lang="en" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 400 200">

  <text transform="translate(200, 30)">
    <tspan>Hello</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">World</tspan>
  </text>

</svg>
```